# How do I set the data for a "PUT" request with AFNetworking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http, afnetworking

I have started to use AFNetworking and it works well when it gets to making simple "GET"-request. However now I am trying to do a "POST"-request. I use the code below to do the "GET" request. When looking at the *puthPath* of *AFHTTPClient* there is no way to set the data to use for the body. My guess is that there is another way of fixing this. I have been looking at the *AFHTTPOperation* as a way of fixing this. However I am not getting this to work. The problem is that I do not know how to use it with Basic Authentication.

Could somebody give me a hint of how to do a simple "POST"-request with AFNetworking?

```
AFHTTPClient* client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:ServerURL];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:self.username 
                                  password:self.password];

NSString* resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/some/resource/%@", 
                          endPath];

[client getPath:resourcePath 
     parameters:nil 
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // Success code omitted
        } 
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // Some error handling code omitted
        }
 ];
```

Comment: I am not able to answer my own question because of to low reputation. Therefore I am posting this comment. I will post this as an answer when I have the possibility to do so.

If did not find any easy way to solve this by using the `code`AFHTTPClient`code`. I did however make a sub-class to `code`AFHTTPClient`code` which is actually recommended in the AFNetworking documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did not find any easy way to do this. But I did as recommended and created my own sub-class of *AFHTTPClient*. In the subclass I implemented the methods below. This makes it possible to perform both POST-request & PUT-requests with my own data.

```
- (void)postPath:(NSString *)path 
  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
        data:(NSData*)data
     success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
     failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path     parameters:parameters data:data];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}

- (void)putPath:(NSString *)path 
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
           data:(NSData*)data
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:path parameters:parameters data:data];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
[self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}

-(NSMutableURLRequest*)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method 
                                    path:(NSString *)path 
                              parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
                                 data:(NSData*)data;
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [super requestWithMethod:method 
                                                      path:path 
                                                parameters:parameters];

    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    return request;
}
```

Comment: You cannot set the data directly anymore. Solution:
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:parameters];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

Answer (score 3):

With AFNetworking 2.0, I just copy code from

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)PUT:(NSString *)URLString
                 parameters:(id)parameters
                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

and add a

```
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Here is it:

```
NSString* str = [bookDetailLink objectForKey:@"Body"];
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:bookingDetailUrl parameters:nil error:nil];

[request setHTTPBody:data];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSHTTPURLResponse *response) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"%@", response);
                                                                  }
                                                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *error) {
                                                                      NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                                  }];

[self.manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

I am integrating Skyscanner API to our iOS app using AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

With AFNetworking 1.3.2 the following code works for me:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumb, 0.85F);

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]
    initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient
    requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"/foo" parameters:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:imageData];
[request setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient 
    HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSHTTPURLResponse *response) {
            NSLog(@"%@", response);
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }];
[operation start];
```

This results in a PUT request with correct headers, Content-Lenght and general RESTfulness :-)