# Afnetworking 2.0 PUT image

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

1. I am able to use put method of afnetworking 2.0 successfully for putting data.

   NSString* PUTURL = [NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"%@/updateestado/estado/%@/idJugador/%ld",BASEURl,[status
                                                                                            urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],userId];

   NSLog(@"REG URL----%@",PUTURL);

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager PUT:PUTURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
       [self.NET_Delegate DelegateUpdateStatusResponce:responseObject];

   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       [self.NET_Delegate DelegateUpdateStatusError:error];
   }];

   2. I am able to upload video successfully using post method.
   3. But The requirement for uploading image is using PUT
      [image]
   4. I followed the way given in
      [Simple "PUT" file upload with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097415/simple-put-file-upload-with-afnetworking)
      but had two issues says multipartFormRequestWithMethod deprived &
      when trying the approach get 404 error.
   5. No reference for this on afnetworking doc in github.
   6. **Query: I am working on uploading image using put first time, so i think i am missing some thing. Any reference or code samples to achieve this will be helpful. Thanks**

Comment: You may be encoding the image incorrectly - does it require a base64 encoding for the PUT request?

Comment: Thanks @Halpo for your comment,  No it doesn't require base64 or any kind of encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not uploading an image; but rather a URL of the image (note the `url` parameter).

Therefore you will need to upload the image to a 3rd party site and then post the link to whatever that service is.

It's impossible to upload an image using a PUT request so you must be missing something.

Comment: The url parameter is the url Example theirwebservicelikelink/USerID/Photos

Comment: as i am successfully posting video with url para (told by them) as theirwebservicelikelink/USerID/Videos/

Comment: url is basilicay the web address to store the file, don't Know why they are using these concept

Comment: @Yogesh.Lolusare.Apple Well it's impossible to upload an image using a `PUT` request so you must be missing something.

Comment: Thanks @TrojanFoe, The point is good & i will try to address this

Comment: if you want you can edit your answer with this point Well it's impossible to upload an image using a PUT request so you must be missing something