# How do you post video data from ios to Signed Url to Google Cloud Bucket?

Tags: ios, swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a python method that successfully creates a GET Signed Url that will download the video that is in the Google Cloud Bucket.

```
def _MakeUrlForApp(self, verb, path, content_type='', content_md5=''):
    """Forms and returns the full signed URL to access GCS."""
    base_url = '%s%s' % (self.gcs_api_endpoint, path)
    signature_string = self._MakeSignatureString(verb, path, content_md5,
                                                 content_type)
    signature_signed = self._Base64Sign(signature_string)

    """replace @ with %40 - and + with %2 and == with %3D"""
    signature_signed = signature_signed.replace("+", "%2B")
    signature_signed = signature_signed.replace("/", "%2F")
    signature_signed = signature_signed.replace("=", "%3D")
    self.client_id_email = self.client_id_email.replace("@", "%40")

    signedURL = base_url + "?Expires=" + str(self.expiration) + "&GoogleAccessId=" + self.client_id_email + "&Signature=" + signature_signed 
    print 'this is the signed URL '
    print signedURL
    return signedURL
```

This is called in ios swift with a get post with http. It returns the signed url and it downloads the video to the ios app.

This method here, If i specify the bucketname, the objectname, text/plain as content type, and a couple words for the data, It creates and puts that file into the Google Cloud bucket for me.

```
    def Put(self, path, content_type, data):
    """Performs a PUT request.
    Args:
      path: The relative API path to access, e.g. '/bucket/object'.
      content_type: The content type to assign to the upload.
      data: The file data to upload to the new file.
    Returns:
      An instance of requests.Response containing the HTTP response.
    """
    md5_digest = base64.b64encode(md5.new(data).digest())

    base_url, query_params = self._MakeUrl('PUT', path, content_type,
                                           md5_digest)
    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
    headers['Content-Length'] = str(len(data))
    headers['Content-MD5'] = md5_digest
    return self.session.put(base_url, params=query_params, headers=headers,
                            data=data)
```

What I want to know is one of these two things and nothing else. How do I upload data from a video to this data parameter in my python webapp2.requestHandler from ios? OR How do I get the correct put signed Url to upload video data?

Please do not comment with anything that will not solve this specific question and do not bash me for my methods. Please provide suggests that you feel will specifically help me and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to upload images to GCS, and each way works with signed URLs. If the video files are small, your simplest option is to have the users perform a non-resumable upload, which has the same URL signature except that the verb is PUT instead of GET. You'll also need to add the "Content-Type"  header to the signature.

Video files can be fairly large, though, so you may prefer to use resumable uploads. These are a bit more complicated but do work with signed URLs as well. You'll need to use the "x-goog-resumable: start" header (and include it in the signature) and set "Content-Length" to 0. You'll get back a response with a Location header containing a new URL. Your client will then use that URL to do the upload. Only the original URL needs to be signed. The client can use the followup URL directly.

Comment: Two things. I created a signed url with the PUT(google signed urls are only GET, PUT, and DELETE. So i created the signed url with a PUT verb, then added "video/quicktime" to content type. Then tried to POST to that returned url. did not work. When I create this signed put url, which im assuming it is the correct one because the GET one created, how do I PUT a video to that url?

Comment: Are you trying to execute a PUT or a POST request? If the signed URL is signed for PUT, you'll need to use PUT.

If you really want to POST instead, then you need to use a signed policy document, which is different: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples

Comment: I am trying to execute a PUT request. Okay now that i have the PUT Url, how do I PUT a video with ios? the PUT method using AFHTTPSessionManager will only take the url and parameters. Do i put the video data in the parameters?

Comment: I am not very familiar with AFNetworking, but this question has been previously answered on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003545/how-do-i-set-the-data-for-a-put-request-with-afnetworking

Comment: That did not answer my question. That answers how to add data to a POST request. But Thank You.

Comment: I too am not fluent with AFNetworking but [`AFHTTPSessionManager` docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/PUT:parameters:success:failure:) don't show any way of including form data with `PUT` requests, only `POST`.  I'm not sure you can use the `parameters` arguments to pass video data but very doubtful.  Have you managed to get this done?  If so, how?